# jQuery Validate custom message for contenteditable span or div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to show a custom error message when a `contenteditable` span is invalid in the form.

My HTML:

```
<div id="errors"></div>
<form method="post" action="#">
    <span required name="first_name" id="first_name" contenteditable placeholder="First Name"></span><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="something" id="something"/><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var validate_messages = {
    first_name: 'Please enter your name',
    something: 'Please enter something'
  }

  $('form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    errorLabelContainer: '#errors',
    wrapper: 'li',
    rules: {
      'first_name': {
        required: true
      },
      'something': {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      'first_name': {
        required: validate_messages['first_name']
      },
      'something': {
        required: validate_messages['something']
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
      alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });
});
```

If I remove the `required` attribute on the `span`, even the default message does not show up. How can I fix this?

Here is the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cu3nn84t/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery validate doesn't handle cases like these.

However, you can handle this manually inside of the the [`showErrors` callback](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) by iterating over all of the `errorList` items and checking to see if the corresponding element has a `[contenteditable]` and `[name]` attribute.

From there, you can get the element's `name` attribute value and map that back to your custom validation message and override the message property on the corresponding `error` object.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ze5p18pe/)

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
  errorList.forEach(function (error) {
    if ($(error.element).is('[contenteditable][name]')) {
      error.message = validate_messages[error.element.getAttribute('name')];
    }
  });

  this.defaultShowErrors();
},
```

Full code snippet based on the code that you provided:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var validate_messages = {
    first_name: 'Please enter your name',
    something: 'Please enter something'
  }

  $('form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    errorLabelContainer: '#errors',
    wrapper: 'li',
    rules: {
      'first_name': {
        required: true
      },
      'something': {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      'first_name': {
        required: validate_messages['first_name']
      },
      'something': {
        required: validate_messages['something']
      }
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
      errorList.forEach(function(error) {
        if ($(error.element).is('[contenteditable][name]')) {
          error.message = validate_messages[error.element.getAttribute('name')];
        }
      });

      this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
      alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div#errors {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div#errors li {
  color: red;
}
span[contenteditable] {
  min-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div id="errors"></div>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <span required name="first_name" id="first_name" contenteditable placeholder="First Name"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="something" id="something" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This works in your specific case, however, there may be some unexpected side effects that I am not aware of due to the fact that jQuery validate was not *initially* designed to validate `span`/`div` elements with a `[contenteditable]` attribute.

As a side note, I searched for `contenteditable`-related issues on the [jQuery validate GitHub repository](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation), and I found [issue #1418](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=contenteditable%20) where it looks like a pull request was merged for adding support for the `contenteditable` attribute. It looks like there are [still numerous related issues](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=contenteditable%20) though, so in the meantime the solution above is a decent work-around until there is official, functioning support for the attribute.

Comment: Perfect! Just the answer I was looking for - Thank you!

Comment: The main issue here is a major bug of this new feature that was apparently never reported.  You cannot assign a rule (or a custom message) via `.validate()`.  I created a new GitHub bug report here:  https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/1946